# JMX monitoring clients for Java

Tags: java, jmx

I would like to monitor a JBoss app using JMX.

Nice graphical representations of MBean values over time is what I am interested in.

I am aware of jconsole and jvisualvm but as far as I can see there is no way to generate a durable single view with multiple graphs of the MBeans I would like to watch.

Are there other third party JMX clients that can do this job better?

Comment: This question isn't a very good fit for SO but if all else fails, you can have a look at Jolokia and using it to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399172/better-options-to-view-jmx-beans-other-than-jconsole).

I have had a look at jManage and Java Mission Control and both look interesting.